# How can I stop Eclipse's auto-completion feature from suggesting made up variable names?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've set up Content Assist to trigger on aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHjIiJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ.() rather than only on .( (Under Window/Preferences/Java/Editor/Content Assist->Auto activation triggers for Java:) so that I can quickly select classes without pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

This was all good until I went back to *creating* variable names rather than using them, and it started suggesting a camel case variant of the name I just type, which doesn't yet exist, suffixed with the type! And of course pressing space afterwards uses this suggestion.

i.e. I type only the keys needed for

```
private static String HELLO = "hello";
```

I'll end up with the line

```
private static String hELLOString = "hello";
```

[image: This comes under Java Proposals (Task-Focused)]

This comes under Java Proposals (Task-Focused), but turning this off under Advanced options obviously removes all the useful suggestions.

My aim is to allow auto-completion using known objects, not make them up, is there a way of doing this, and if so, How?

Comment: When you are creating a variable name Eclipse will suggest a name that ends with the type of the variable because that's the only guess it can make hence this result.

Comment: ... which is why the default is NOT to attempt auto-completion until the user asks for it.

Comment: @bvidal do you know how I can turn off guesses?

Comment: Just like suggested by @keshlam auto-complete defaults behavior to be used only on user request is for a reason. And I don't think you can turn those off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *reduce the likelihood* of accidentally selecting suggested variable names by increasing  the 'Auto activation delay (ms)', and making sure that when you type a variable name you press [space] or [;] immediately afterwards before thinking about what to type next (if you haven't already).

Unfortunately there is no way (at least in the current Kepler SR1 release) of turning off variable name suggestion without also losing declared variable name suggestion, which is too useful to lose.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're asking for code completion at a point (variable declaration) where there are no correct answers since only you know what name you want to enter.  Eclipse does try to suggest a possible name, as you point out, from the already-entered type, but it can only guess.

Once you've declared the variable, Eclipse will be able to offer up that correct variable name later on in the code.

Comment: Exactly, when "there are no correct answers", I don't want Eclipse to give me an answer ;)